# Why does flashing my Tab3, 7.0, 8GB, WiFi (sm-t210) fail with Odin?

Tags: rom-flashing, odin, samsung-galaxy-tab-3

I tried several versions of Odin and also several ROM's, yet successfully flashing still seem to fail.

```
<OSM> Enter CS for MD5..
<OSM> Check MD5.. Do not unplug the cable..
<OSM> Please wait..
<OSM> Checking MD5 finished Sucessfully..
<OSM> Leave CS..
<ID:0/005> Added!!
<ID:0/005> Odin engine v(ID:3.1301)..
<ID:0/005> File analysis..
<ID:0/005> Total Binary size: 1397 M
<ID:0/005> SetupConnection..
<ID:0/005> Initialzation..
<ID:0/005> Get PIT for mapping..
<ID:0/005> Firmware update start..
<ID:0/005> NAND Write Start!!
<ID:0/005> SingleDownload.
<ID:0/005> PBL.bin
<ID:0/005> FAIL!
<ID:0/005>
<ID:0/005> Complete(Write) operation failed.
<OSM> All threads completed. (succeed 0 / failed 1
```

Please observe that with the newest version of Odin in the log above 'Get PIT for mapping' and 'PBL.bin' failed.

```
<ID:0/005> Added!!
<ID:0/005> Removed!!
<ID:0/005> Added!!
<OSM> Enter CS for MD5..
<OSM> Check MD5.. Do not unplug the cable..
<OSM> Please wait..
<OSM> T210XXBNI1_T210PHNBNI1_T210XXBNI1_HOME.tar.md5 is valid.
<OSM> Checking MD5 finished Sucessfully..
<OSM> Leave CS..
<ID:0/005> Odin v.3 engine (ID:5)..
<ID:0/005> File analysis..
<ID:0/005> SetupConnection..
<ID:0/005> Initialzation..
<ID:0/005> Get PIT for mapping..
<ID:0/005> Firmware update start..
<ID:0/005> SingleDownload.
<ID:0/005> PBL.bin
<ID:0/005> NAND Write Start!!
<ID:0/005> FAIL!
<ID:0/005>
<ID:0/005> Complete(Write) operation failed.
<OSM> All threads completed. (succeed 0 / failed 1)
```

Please observe with an older version of Odin that in the log above 'Get PIT for mapping' and 'NAND write' failed.

The stock ROM I seem to need for this device 'SM-T210, Tab3, 7.0, 8GB WiFi, has these specs: KOT49H, T210XXBOB1, PHN, build date Feb 3 2015, Android version 4.4.2
Kernel version: 3.4.5-4081557
I'm not sure if it's KitKat or Jelly Bean as both seem to have similar versions of Android.
So what's going wrong here?

Comment: I've been trying several versions of Odin, from the newest to the older versions 1.85, 1.87. In the mean time I've been trying yet another version of Odin 3.07 and that seem to finish successfully, yet on the Tab3 I don't see any progressbar, nothing. So when the device reboot after Odin finishes ... nothing seem to be changed. I'd try other USB ports too, but that didn't do the trick. All being left for now is another cable. Until today I've been using a Nokia branded charge/data cable, which seem to work fine for browsing the Tab3. But this week will show if that's the cause of failures.

Comment: Are there specific requirements to that micro B USB cable in use with either Odin of Samsung?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many times I tried to repair that device, but when the volume up/down buttons start to fail, it is game over. So I had to quit.

Answer (score 0):

As Odin in Windows doesn't seem to work for my device, I tried another application such as Heimdall-Frontend.
This application differs from Odin in that it uses the extracted files from a stock ROM where as Odin uses the stock ROM to upload to an connected device.
Anyways, I found that from Heimdall all files are successfully downloaded to the Samsung Tab3 device.
Yet there was a slight difference between the download of 'system.img' file and all the other 9 files out of the stock ROM.
After the download from Heimdall completed, it was released and right after that the Tab3 device goes into reboot.
While after the download of all other 9 files, it took a few seconds before the Tab3 goes into reboot.
So my guess here is that right after being released, the Tab3 goes immediately into reboot and deletes that way the successful downloaded 'system.img' file.
That would also explain as to why there's no change after the successful flashing with Heimdall.